# Programmatically get "Find My Phone" status in iOS?

Tags: ios

Is there any way to get "Find my phone" status in iOS?
I didn't find any iOS SDK API to get that status.

Comment: No this is not possible, as you have discovered there are no API in the official API.

Comment: what status you are looking for?

Comment: @JagveerSingh: I want to get the status (Enable or Disable) setting for "Find My Phone" feature. How can I get it?